# Should I flag users for a single horribly erroneous review?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags

Sometimes I see reviews which are horribly erroneous by any objective standard; the most common seem to be:

- Clicking "Looks OK" or "Requires editing" in the triage queue while it very clearly should have been "Unsalvageable".
- Approving edits (especially tag edits) which are very obviously copied content.
- Approving edits which make the post objectively and significantly worse (such as introducing syntax errors).

Should I flag such users with a custom moderator flag by flagging one of their posts?

On one hand this could help solve the long-standing "robo-reviewer" problem, but on the other hand it would add to the moderators' already heavy workload.